# c# add a new variable with new row in datagridview

Tags: c#, variables, datagridview, runtime, formula

I try to calculate something in a datagridview, so you can add new lines. Now comes my question. Is it possible to add the cell to a variable when a new line is created and is a value in it so that the formula is also derived? Is that possible?

Example:

Line 1: 10 | 02 |

Line 2: 08 | 15 |

Line 3: 02 | 05 |

Formula:

10 + 02

08 + 15

02 + 05

Solution:12, 23, 7

And when I add a 4th line it expands the formula.$
Sorry for the bad english :/

Comment: Look at the grids "Row" events. RowLeave could be of some use. You can add code to sum up all values in the grid rows for columns 1 and 2 for example. You dont need to expand the formula, just iterate through all rows in the grid.

Comment: Where are you wanting to keep/display the solution? You may want to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that shows how SO works. In addition, you may want to peruse, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also if you need [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Finally, you may want to look at… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)